# Como guardar datos de session del lado del servidor como en php, pero con react?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs

Buenas estoy migrando una página de php a react, pero tengo varios codigos que se persisten en la session. En react, se que puedo persistirlo en el local del cliente, pero quisiera evitar escribirle datos al cliente en su pc (store, cookies, etc), quisiera seguir manteniendo esa persistencia desde el servidor. Pero no se que framework de react permite eso, quizas Next?
Acepto sugerencias por favor. He intentado investigar y no he encontrado algo que me pueda responder eso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que persista en local no hay mas opciones que las que comentas, que es basicamente localStorage (o cookies).

Si no quieres guardar esos datos en el servidor no hay mas manera...

Otra cosa es guardarlos en el estado del componente (ya sea en un estado local para el propio componente o un estado global de la App como Redux) ...

Pero al final este estado se reiniciará al recargar la pagina, por ejemplo. Asi que si tu quieres más persistencia de datos... en algún lugar hay que almacenarlos, claro. (o servidor o en local)

Un saludo.